# customizing the blog page of wp2014 child theme

Tags: wordpress

i am developing a child theme using wordpress2014 theme.currently my blog page looks like this. [image: current view of my blog page]

i would like to add some links before the starting of all posts listing. how can i get this done? i have already tried to edit the content.php file in tweentyfourteen theme. but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your index.php to add links above your posts (the loop).